# running number/counter (e.g. {244}{a}) for a text

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering, counters, eledmac

To assign a running counter to parts (not paragraphs, not lines) of a
document with facing greek text and translation (finally I will use
`eledpar`) I need a command (call it `\Steph`) which 1a) inserts a mark
(preferably `\apex` from `teubner.sty`) in the text, b) prints the running
number in the margin, and 2. assigns a number to each part of
the text, so that I can refer to it later (e.g. `\labelSteph` & `\refSteph`).

We Platonists refer to any passage with a two-part number: The
*pagenumber* of the first printed edition
(-->http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephanus_pagination with  http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/ae/Theaetetus_stephanus_page142.jpg)
and a letter (a, b, c, d, e) for the *part* the (original) page. So the 
first part of my sample text is, e.g., 244a, followed by 244b
... 244e, 245a, 245b ...

BUT: I don't want it to print 244a, 244b ... in the margin, but 244
(="244a starts"), b (="244b, 244 taken from above"), c ... 245, b ...

Of the many LuaLaTeX packages (`xpatch`, `suffix` ...), I use only a `\xparse`-command, which doesn't really do what I want.

```
% -*- mode: latex; TeX-engine: luatex; coding: utf-8; -*-
\documentclass[parskip=false]{scrbook}
\usepackage{eledmac,savesym,fontspec}
\setmainfont{texgyrepagella-regular.otf}
\newfontfamily\greekfont{GFS Porson}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands = true]{german}
\setotherlanguage{greek}
\usepackage{teubner}
\savesymbol{breve} %to avoid a clash
\sidenotemargin{outer}
\NewDocumentCommand{\Steph}{ m m }{\ledsidenote{\textlatin{\emph{#1"|#2}}}\apex}
\usepackage{xparse}
\begin{document}
\beginnumbering
\selectlanguage{greek}
  \pstart ΣΩ.\quad Οὑτωσὶ τοίνυν, ὦ παῖ καλέ, ἐννόησον, ὡς ὁ μὲν
  πρότερος ἦν \Steph{244}{a}λόγος Φαίδρου τοῦ Πυθοκλέους, Μυρρινουσίου
  ἀνδρός. ὃν δὲ μέλλω λέγειν Στησιχόρου τοῦ Εὐφήμου, Ἱμεραίου. λεκτέος
  δὲ ὧδε, ὅτι οὐκ ἔστ’\,ἔτυμος λόγος ὃς ἂν παρόντος ἐραστοῦ τῷ μὴ
  ἐρῶντι φῇ δεῖν χαρίζεσθαι, διότι δὴ ὁ μὲν μαίνεται, ὁ δὲ
  σωφρονεῖ. [...]

  Ἥ τε γὰρ ἐν ∆ελφοῖς \labelSteph{Delphi}προφῆτις αἵ τ’\,ἐν
  ∆ω\Steph{244}{b}δώνῃ ἱέρειαι μανεῖσαι μὲν πολλὰ δὴ καὶ καλὰ ἰδίᾳ τε
  καὶ δημοσίᾳ τὴν Ἑλλάδα ἠργάσαντο, σωφρονοῦσαι δὲ βραχέα ἢ οὐδέν. καὶ
  ἐὰν δὴ λέγωμεν Σίβυλλάν τε καὶ ἄλλους, ὅσοι μαντικῇ χρώμενοι ἐνθέῳ
  πολλὰ δὴ πολλοῖς προλέγοντες εἰς τὸ μέλλον ὤρθωσαν, [...]\pend
\endnumbering

\selectlanguage{german}Over Delphi speaken Plato in \refSteph{Delphi}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am not sur to understand your problem. Is it to make \Steph{244}{a} produce 244 and after that \Steph{244}{b} produce b? In this case, do you have to try if \Steph{244}{b} follows \Steph{244}{a} or is it certain?What is the link with eledmac?

Comment: Yes. 1. *Print* "244" in the margin (instead of, e.g., 244a), but print "b" (instead of, e.g., 244b) (=never print number"|letter in the margin), but 2. *assign* the value 244a to the part of the text from, e.g., \Steph{244}{a} to \Steph{244}{b}, so that I get "244a" with `\refSteph{Delphi}`. `marginnote`, `marginpar`, `ledsidenote` ... all have their own pitfalls, so I use `\ledsidenote` right from the beginning.

Comment: hum, there is two problem in your question a) print b and not a -> easy b) new ref counter-> more difficult

Comment: If 1a and 1b *is* easy -- I think it is --, then *do* the thing! A question like 2 came up with paragraphs of the New Testament, but handling fixed sections is much easier than arbitrary passages.

Answer (score 2):

The question's not terribly clear, but I think you want something like:

[image]

```
\documentclass[parskip=false]{scrbook}
\usepackage{eledmac,savesym,fontspec}
\setmainfont{texgyrepagella-regular.otf}
\newfontfamily\greekfont{GFS Porson}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands = true]{german}
\setotherlanguage{greek}
\usepackage{teubner}
\savesymbol{breve} %to avoid a clash
\sidenotemargin{outer}
\makeatletter

% don't know what these commands do
%\NewDocumentCommand{\Steph}{ m m }{\def\@currentlabel{#1#2}\ledsidenote{\textlatin{\emph{#1"|#2}}}\apex}
\NewDocumentCommand{\Steph}{ m m }{\def\@currentlabel{#1#2}\ledsidenote{%
\textlatin{\if a#2 #1\else #2\fi}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\beginnumbering
\selectlanguage{greek}
  \pstart ΣΩ.\quad Οὑτωσὶ τοίνυν, ὦ παῖ καλέ, ἐννόησον, ὡς ὁ μὲν
  πρότερος ἦν \Steph{244}{a}λόγος Φαίδρου τοῦ Πυθοκλέους, Μυρρινουσίου
  ἀνδρός. ὃν δὲ μέλλω λέγειν Στησιχόρου τοῦ Εὐφήμου, Ἱμεραίου. λεκτέος
  δὲ ὧδε, ὅτι οὐκ ἔστ’\,ἔτυμος λόγος ὃς ἂν παρόντος ἐραστοῦ τῷ μὴ
  ἐρῶντι φῇ δεῖν χαρίζεσθαι, διότι δὴ ὁ μὲν μαίνεται, ὁ δὲ
  σωφρονεῖ. [...]

  Ἥ τε γὰρ ἐν ∆ελφοῖς \label{Delphi}προφῆτις αἵ τ’\,ἐν
  ∆ω\Steph{244}{b}δώνῃ ἱέρειαι μανεῖσαι μὲν πολλὰ δὴ καὶ καλὰ ἰδίᾳ τε
  καὶ δημοσίᾳ τὴν Ἑλλάδα ἠργάσαντο, σωφρονοῦσαι δὲ βραχέα ἢ οὐδέν. καὶ
  ἐὰν δὴ λέγωμεν Σίβυλλάν τε καὶ ἄλλους, ὅσοι μαντικῇ χρώμενοι ἐνθέῳ
  πολλὰ δὴ πολλοῖς προλέγοντες εἰς τὸ μέλλον ὤρθωσαν, [...]\pend
\endnumbering

\selectlanguage{german}Over Delphi speaken Plato in \ref{Delphi}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `\apex`, taken from `teubner.sty`, inserts a hook at the point where 244a ends and 244b begins (a linebreak in the Stephanus-edition where I get the numbering from). I have to define a new hook: `\DeclareRobustCommand*{\Stephpex}{\vrule\@height1.7ex\@depth-1ex}
\NewDocumentCommand{\Steph}{ m m }{\Stephpex\def\@currentlabel{#1#2}\ledsidenote{%
\textlatin{\if a#2 #1\else #2\fi}}}`. The other thing is: 1. It would be best -- if one can do -- to create a new label (`\labelSteph`) to avoid conflict with, e.g., `eledmac`'s `\label`, and 2. to print it as 244{\somespace}a instead of 244a.

Comment: Anyhow, sometimes one needs 244a, though the command removes the a, or 244b, when the 244 is removed. So I define a starred version of the command `\DeclareRobustCommand*{\Stephpex}{\vrule\@height1.7ex\@depth-1ex}
\NewDocumentCommand{\Steph}{s m m}{% 
\IfBooleanTF#1{%
\Stephpex\def\@currentlabel{#2#3}\ledsidenote{\textlatin{#2\hrsp#3}}}{%
\Stephpex\def\@currentlabel{#2#3}\ledsidenote{\textlatin{\if a#3 #2\else #3\fi}}}}`